# VS Community 2015 Losing Focus when using Quick Action shortcut

Tags: visual-studio-2015, refactoring, quickaction

I'm currently refactoring my codebase and changing some of the naming on my types and members. I use Quick Action for easily renaming all of the instances of the types or members, but if I use the shortcut for this (Ctrl + .) then I'll lose mouse focus on the file I'm working on and have to click in it in order to be able to type again.

Does anyone know a shortcut or setting that fixes this issue?

Comment: I'm seeing the same problem in VS 2015 Enterprise.